# IBM Raspberry Pi IoT Service

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, iot, cloud-foundry

I am working on a small IoT project using a Raspberry Pi 3, running Raspian 9.6 and Cloud Foundry services from IBM.  These IBM services include a Python CF App and a Watson IoT service.

To get the Python board to talk to the IBM cloud, per IBM documentation I installed the following:

```
sudo dpkg -i iot_1.0-2_armhf.deb
```

After I added the Raspberry PI to the IBM Watson IoT service in the Cloud, I stopped and restarted the service (sudo service iot start) on the Raspberry Pi and I could immediately see that the device connected to the IBM Cloud.

```
Token auth succeeded: ClientID='d:xxxxx:raspberrypi:xxxxxxxx', ClientIP=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Dec 18, 2018 6:22 PM
```

What I did NOT expect was to see was messages being generated by the Raspberry Pi and flowing into the Cloud.  Ex:

```
{
    "d": {
        "myName": "myPi",
        "cputemp": 44.01,
        "cpuload": 0.01,
        "sine": 0.38
    }
}
```

I can't find anything that talks about this.  I'd like to know:

1. Is this a standard behaviour of the iot service on the Pi?
2. Where is the IBM documentation for this?  (I can't find it.)
3. Can I tap into this and use this in lieu of a client app that I am writing?
4. Where is message.txt at?

I think of this service as a normal Windows or Linux service, I just did not expect it to act as an application.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I realized after I posted that I should have looked for the source online.

**iot_1.0-2_armhf.deb** is located at:

https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot/device-raspberrypi/releases

I have the answers that I need.

Thanks